# Using linux device as a firewall routing configuration

Tags: routes, ip, virtual-machine, config

I have  vm1 (10.1.1.11) -> 10.1.1.12 |vm2 (firewall)| 10.3.3.7 -> 10.3.3.8 (vm3)
and they are all connected to the external network. I want to transfer files from vm1 to vm3 using vm2 as the firewall. However, I am having trouble configuring the route. When I tracepath vm3 from vm1, it goes directly to it (it goes through the external network). How do I make it go through the firewall? Heres my routing table for vm1.

default via 192.168.128.1 dev eth0
10.1.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.11
10.1.1.12 via 10.1.1.11 dev eth0
10.3.3.0/24 via 10.1.1.11 dev eth0
192.168.128.0/20 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.128.234

Answer (score 0):

Add these two routes:

1. On **VM1**, add a route where the destination is **VM3**, and the next hop
   (gateway) is **VM2**.
2. On **VM3**, add a route where the destination is **VM1**,
   and the next hop (gateway) is **VM2**.

Then make sure that ip_forwarding is enabled in VM2